# Is there a way to disable chromes "same-origin" policy using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, iframe, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to write a script in which I scrape elements inside an iframe but am getting

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://kith.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

I've tried this script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

chop = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chop.add_argument("--disable-web-security")

# create new Chrome driver object with Chrome extension

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', options=chop)
```

and with my chrome extension I tried scraping an element inside an iframe but it said it still gave me that error